# How to pass a file name to sed|grep|awk command inside a variable assignment in unix

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, sed

Im trying to execute the following script to get the currentpath string  from a file and pass it to find and replace in the next command. it works fine when running directly in the host server , but when tried to execute from jenkins build step, i'm getting  a failure that file not found.

Error: sed: can't read test.txt: No such file or directory

Expected result is to get the "test.txt" file updated with "newPath" wherever the "currentPath" exists

code :

```
user="testuser"
host="remotehost"
newPath="/testpath/"
filetoUpdate="./test.txt" # this is a file 
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ${user}@${host} "currentPath="$(sed -n '/^PATH='/p $filetoUpdate | cut -d'=' -f2)" ; echo  "currentPath was "$currentPath"" ; sed -n 's|$currentPath|$newPath|g' $filetoUpdate"
```

Comment: "currentpath string from a file" what is that? Maybe an example would help? Are you perhaps trying to re-implement `basename` or `dirname`?

Comment: Variable substitution for filetoUpdate is done on local host. So it looks for ./test.txt locally not on remote host.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg - Ok any suggestion on how to make it look for the file at the remote server? im able do an ls on current directory on remote server which perfectly lists the  file im intrested in.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - in the file test.txt , i have a line "PATH=/path/tp/data/directory/" I need to find this path and replace with new path .

Comment: You have a bunch of code there, which part exactly doesn't work? Which part does work? Please provide a [mcve] which you extract from your code and which enables anyone to reproduce your issue. In particular, unravel the mystery of how Jenkins and SSH are relevant! [edit] your question to clarify these things.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that locally defined variables newPath and filetoUpdate will not be available in script running on remote host. Also in this script only currentPath= will be executed on remote host, rest of the commands run locally.

I'd recommend to save script in a separate file.
test.sh:

```
newPath="/testpath/"
filetoUpdate="./test.txt" 
currentPath=`sed -n '/^PATH=/p' $filetoUpdate | cut -d= -f2`  
echo  "currentPath was "$currentPath""  
sed -i .bak "s|$currentPath|$newPath|g" $filetoUpdate
```

(I added -i for in-site editing)
And to run it with the command

```
ssh remotehost < t.sh
```